# issue with sqlite while installing SVN::Core

Tags: git, perl, sqlite, svn, redhat

I am trying to install SVN::Core in a Redhat 6 server, but every time I try to run cpan SVN::Core, it throws me an error that says:

An appropriate version of sqlite could not be found.  We recommmend
3.7.15.1, but require at least 3.7.12.
Please either install a newer sqlite on this system or get the sqlite 3.7.15.1 amalgamation from:
    http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
unpack the archive using unzip and rename the resulting
directory to: /root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-9/src/subversion/sqlite-amalgamation

The first time I tried to install it it told me to rename the sqlite file(sqlite-amalgamation-3071501) in the path:

/root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-1/

the next time to the Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-2,

the third time to 11.0-3, and it goes on and on.

Before doing this I installed the Perl 5.18.2 and set the PERL5LIB with export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

`cpan` uses a fresh directory every time is runs an install (by default).

After placing the `sqlite` files under `/root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-XXX`, run the following commands:

```
cd /root/.cpan/build/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0-XXX
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build test
./Build install   # If the tests passed.
```

Then, do `cpan SVN::Core` again.